# have to click two times to call an onclick

Tags: android, button, onclick, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to create an **Introduction Activity** appears only once after user click in **skip** button , **skip** button allows user to go to **mainactivity**
my problem i have is when I click skip button don't get anything until I press twice or three times ,after that skip button works well I really don't know the reason why Onclick method dosen't work 
this my code :

```
public class intro extends Activity {
   Button skip;
    SharedPreferences appPreferences;
    boolean isclick = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);
        skip = (Button)findViewById(R.id.skip);
        hide();
        appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        isclick= appPreferences.getBoolean("isclick",false);
        if(isclick){
            Intent toMain = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(toMain);
        }
        skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!isclick){
                    Intent toMain = new Intent(intro.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(toMain);
                    finish();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("isclick", true);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Just add `Log.e("clicked","clicked")` in your `onClickListener()` before if condition and check weather that the event is working or not

Comment: I suggest you to add the Log before your if condition and check weather you getting the correct Log

Comment: If your skip is text view then there area  is small then that would be  problem .as per above comment first add log and then analyze .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your isClick logic doesn't make sense to me. Rather than always running this intro, but then immediately starting mainactivity on top if isclick is true, why not have the logic for whether to do the intro in mainactivity. Something like this in mainactivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences appPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (!appPreferences.getBoolean("introSkipped", false)) {
        Intent toIntro = new Intent(this,Intro.class);
        startActivity(toIntro);
    } else {
    // continue with main as normal
    }
}
```

And then, your onClick for the skip button simply becomes:

```
        skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                      
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = appPreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("introSkipped", true);
                editor.apply();
                finish();                
        }
    });
```

Comment: the mainacivity should be the launcher activity right ?

Comment: yes - so you may need to change your manifest. It seems in your code you have a MainActivity.class, so I assume it's that for you

Comment: thanks so much its works fine , but not smooth one android api 21 when i click the button i should wait 2 second after mainactivity come , I know it's a strange problem

Comment: this depends on what is happening with your mainActivity code. You could take out the "else" part of the main activity introSkipped check, so it will launch the intro on top, and continue with MainActivity behind... I don't know if this will affect the smoothness of your intro though. It's a different question really. Glad my answer worked :-)